# Why is the causalimpact package not recognizing the date index in my dataframe?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm running into an issue with the [causalimpact package](https://github.com/WillianFuks/tfcausalimpact) not recognizing the date index in my dataframe.

I get the error 20210626 not present in input data index. The blob below includes the traceback of the error.

```js
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
Input In [97], in <cell line: 3>()
      1 pre_period = ['20210626','20210628']
      2 post_period = ['20210629','20210702']
----> 3 ci = CausalImpact(data, pre_period, post_period)

File ~/homebrew/lib/python3.8/site-packages/causalimpact/main.py:228, in CausalImpact.__init__(self, data, pre_period, post_period, model, alpha, **kwargs)
    227 def __init__(self, data, pre_period, post_period, model=None, alpha=0.05, **kwargs):
--> 228     checked_input = self._process_input_data(
    229         data, pre_period, post_period, model, alpha, **kwargs
    230     )
    231     super(CausalImpact, self).__init__(**checked_input)
    232     self.model_args = checked_input['model_args']

File ~/homebrew/lib/python3.8/site-packages/causalimpact/main.py:377, in CausalImpact._process_input_data(self, data, pre_period, post_period, model, alpha, **kwargs)
    374     raise ValueError('{args} input cannot be empty'.format(
    375                      args=', '.join(none_args)))
    376 processed_data = self._format_input_data(data)
--> 377 pre_data, post_data = self._process_pre_post_data(processed_data, pre_period,
    378                                                   post_period)
    379 alpha = self._process_alpha(alpha)
    380 model_args = self._process_model_args(**kwargs)

File ~/homebrew/lib/python3.8/site-packages/causalimpact/main.py:658, in CausalImpact._process_pre_post_data(self, data, pre_period, post_period)
    637 def _process_pre_post_data(self, data, pre_period, post_period):
    638     """
    639     Checks `pre_period`, `post_period` and returns data sliced accordingly to  each
    640     period.
   (...)
    656       ValueError: if pre_period last value is bigger than post intervention period.
    657     """
--> 658     checked_pre_period = self._process_period(pre_period, data)
    659     checked_post_period = self._process_period(post_period, data)
    661     if checked_pre_period[1] > checked_post_period[0]:

File ~/homebrew/lib/python3.8/site-packages/causalimpact/main.py:727, in CausalImpact._process_period(self, period, data)
    725         if isinstance(point, pd.Timestamp):
    726             point = point.strftime('%Y%m%d')
--> 727         raise ValueError("{point} not present in input data index.".format(
    728             point=str(point)
    729             )
    730         )
    731 if isinstance(period[0], str) or isinstance(period[0], pd.Timestamp):
    732     period = self._convert_str_period_to_int(period, data)

ValueError: 20210626 not present in input data index.
```

The code and the sample data are given below. Can anyone help with this?

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import tensorflow as tf
import tensorflow_probability as tfp
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from causalimpact import CausalImpact

data = pd.read_csv('~/datasets/results_covariates.csv',encoding='utf-8')
data.set_index('DT', inplace=True, drop=False)

pre_period = ['20210626','20210628']
post_period = ['20210629','20210702']
ci = CausalImpact(data, pre_period, post_period)
```

```
DT  Y   X1  X2
6/26/21 1016.15 8616.033333 164
6/27/21 1174.983333 18156.85    444
6/28/21 56571.43333 417270.6    11664
6/29/21 64821.75    420466.3167 11322
6/30/21 178269.8    2331084.75  66434
7/1/21  62314.28333 391890.9    11221
7/2/21  141387.3833 1286635.85  35207
```

Comment: Please [edit] to put the exact error message/s, the one that starts with "Traceback".

Comment: @GinoMempin thanks! i've updated the post to add the exact error message

Comment: @GinoMempin thanks again for the pointer! i didn't think to look through the main.py file and look at the actual functions under the hood. i figured it out thanks to your comment, thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

Managed to get this working.

causalimpact expects the index to either be an int, str or pd.Timestamp and the dt column had to be reformatted after reading in from my csv / database connector in actual code.

```
data['DT'] = pd.to_datetime(data['DT'])
```